# 'Bring forward' Data Frame Extent Indicator in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, graphics

I want to 'order-> bring forward' the data frame extent indicator I have in an arcmap layout document. I want it to be on top of one graphic feature and under another.

This option is not available though, and other features in the document do not relate to it. How do I get it to appear 'on top'?!

Comment: You could create a shapefile from the dataframe using this add-in: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0dcb445291bf461bb573b1504c170e0c

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @JamesW:

> You could create a shapefile from the dataframe using this add-in:
>   http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0dcb445291bf461bb573b1504c170e0c

That **Create Data Frame polygon** add-in:

> Creates a polygon from the current map extent. Particularly useful in
>   creating extent rectangles for maps or shapes for a graphical index.